# need to clarify things with x[y]

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain in detail what exactly is going on in `x[y]` pairs? I tried console logging but no useful info. I am particularly interested in the operation within the `if` block.

```
let arr = ['a','b','b','c','c','c']
let obj = {}

arr.forEach((element) => {
    if (obj[element]){
        obj[element]++
    }else{
        obj[element] = 1
    }
})
console.log(obj) //{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the IF blocks:

`if(obj[element])` just means if `element` exists as a key in `obj`.
Here, if `element` does not exist within `obj`, create a new key called `element`, assign it the value of `1` (currently one instance of it existing)
If `element` exists as a key within `obj`, add `1` to the key `element` in obj (to increase the count)

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering my question. unfortunately I am not allowed to upvote your answer